# Pentaho replace variables in a query defined in a properties file

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-cde

I have a query defined in a properties file like this

config.properties

```
DYNAMIC_SELECT=select * from accounts where username=${username}
```

I then have a **Table Input** where the variable DYNAMIC_SELECT is used like this

${DYNAMIC_SELECT}

How should I setup my transformation such that the Table Input works?

Comment: Would you provide more information? Full path of file you've changed, what you want to achieve, is this ETL process (look like it is) or BI (front end)..

Comment: This is an ETI process. I want to create a dynamic query but with some parameters of the query coming from a environment variables and the query itself defined in a config file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need quotes around the variable name if it's a string. The variable is replaced verbatim, quotes are not added automatically by the table input step. Otherwise, it should work, I've used dynamic queries with variables therein without issue in several projects.